# Java turn linked hashmap to a string array

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I have a linkedhash map which has a key of the sentence number and the value the score of the sentence.

```
4=104
3=104
1=106
7=130
8=139
9=168
2=199
5=330
```

I need to keep it in this order because it is a text summiraztion program. I also have a array of string which contains each of the sentences which have been seperated using puncutation. How would I create a new string array which the first key will be sentence 4 corresponding to the first key in the linkedhash map. The last key in the array will be sentence 5.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you speak of a "key" relating to a string array?

Comment: `HashMap<Integer, String> test = new HashMap<Integer, String>();  test.put(4, "My sentence.");  System.out.println(test.get(4));`  Just keep a separate `int[]` with your keys in the order you want `{4, 3, etc... 5}` then loop at that array and use the key to retrieve the sentence from the `HashMap`.

Comment: Sorry I mean index of a string array like [0], how would I implement to code above in a for loop

Comment: @TobyDrane still not sure what you are trying to do?

Comment: @TobyDrane are the numbers on the left the order (`index` of the array) and the numbers on the right `key` to a `HashMap`?

Comment: The indices of an array are always in order; they're not keys, they're just the position. `array[0]` **always** refers to the first element of the array. Maybe you should provide us with some code indicating what you are actually trying to do, and what you've tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like -

```
List<String> orderedSentenceList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : yourMap.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    orderedSentenceList.add(originalSentenceList.get(key-1))
}
```

Use orderedSentenceList now

Comment: Yes but my previous sentenceList was a string array String[] not a hashmap.

Comment: I have used previousSententenceList as list not map. If it is String[] then you can use originalSentenceList[key-1].

yourMap is the map which used in your question in the top

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;

String[] array = new String[map.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    array[i++] = entry.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question but here goes:

This is using `String[]` only as you requested.

```
String[] sentenceList = new String[yourLinkedHashMap.size()];
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : yourLinkedHashMap.entrySet()) {
   sentenceList[entry.getKey() - 1] = entry.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will help you develop your own solution

```
 String []sentences=new String[mp.size()] ;
 //mp is the map
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    int i=0;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
         Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
         sentences[i++]=pair.getValue();
    }
```